# MongoDB Aggregate to make the nested aray as Root

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this structure from my aggregate where I am fetching the items and each item has an array of inventory items. And I want to make the nested inventory items array as the main Root result. I have added some demonstration of what the result is and what I actually want.

```
[
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b8",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b9",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af514",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "inventory": [
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce10",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af515",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af515",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

And I want something like this.

```
[
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
        {
          "_id": "603fb4d4dd0c9134c8ce59b7",
          "item_id": "60145c769bd3b700087af513",
          "createdAt": "2021-01-29T19:05:26.166Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-03-27T09:46:07.300Z",
        },
  ]
}
```

Like I want to merge all the results in the Root result. Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/xA14K2mLuiK

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$inventory" }, // to individual documents
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$inventory" } } // replace the root with inventory value
])
```

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

> Replaces the input document with the specified document. The operation replaces all existing fields in the input document, including the _id field. You can promote an existing embedded document to the top level, or create a new document for promotion (see example).

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.